Module::Pluggable installation failed while running the test
While installing Module::pluggable, its failing during test.
Command using to install:
cpanm --mirror https://artifactory.factset.com/artifactory/cpan.org/ Module::Pluggable

LOG:
t/29unreadable.t ............. 1/6 
#   Failed test at t/29unreadable.t line 31.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = 'Unreadable::Foo'
#     $expected->[0] = Does not exist

#   Failed test at t/29unreadable.t line 36.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[0] = 'Unreadable::Foo'
#     $expected->[0] = Does not exist
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 6.
t/29unreadable.t ............. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/6 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/29unreadable.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 6 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  2, 4
  Non-zero exit status: 2

Is there any change? We can use force but not sure why it's failing. I have perl version: 5.16.0.
When used force it skipped the test and installation is successful. I am also trying to install datetime module which is somehow dependent on Module::Pluggable

The test is checking to see if Module::Pluggable ignores modules it doesn't have permission to read.
Let's assume the problem being reported is a problem with Module::Pluggable itself and not with the test. The worse that will happen if you install the module despite the error is that Module::Pluggable won't ignore modules it doesn't have permission to read. That's not something to worry about. As such, I would go ahead and install it.

That RT issue has a patch for systems installing under root, where the superuser can read things the test does not expect.
If you are running this as root (don't, maybe?), install it without running the tests:
% cpanm -n --mirror https://artifactory.factset.com/artifactory/cpan.org/ Module::Pluggable

